# Установка Zeos на Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Как установить компонент zeos на Delphi XE8?

Comment: Поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, какие подходы используете и что хотите видеть в ответе?

Answer (score 2):

Открываешь файл: \ZEOSDBO-7.1.4-stable\src\Zeos.inc
Находишь код:

```
// Compilation directives for Delphi XE7 by miab3
{$IFDEF VER280}
  {$DEFINE VER200BELOW} // Used in code
  {$DEFINE DELPHI12_UP} // Used in code
  {$DEFINE DELPHI14_UP} // used in tests only
  {$DEFINE DELPHI15_UP} // Used in zeos.inc only
  {$DEFINE DELPHI16_UP} // Used in code
  {$DEFINE DELPHI17_UP} // Used in zeos.inc only
  {$DEFINE DELPHI18_UP} // Used in zeos.inc only
  {$DEFINE DELPHI19_UP} // Used in zeos.inc only
  {$DEFINE DELPHI20_UP} //By dieletro Used in zeos.inc only
  {$DEFINE DELPHI21_UP} //Used in zeos.inc only
  {$DEFINE BDS4_UP} // Used in code
  {$DEFINE BDS5_UP} // Used in code
{$ENDIF}
```

и после него пишешь:

```
// Compilation directives for Delphi XE8 by rareMax
{$IFDEF VER290}
  {$DEFINE VER200BELOW} // Used in code
  {$DEFINE DELPHI12_UP} // Used in code
  {$DEFINE DELPHI14_UP} // used in tests only
  {$DEFINE DELPHI15_UP} // Used in zeos.inc only
  {$DEFINE DELPHI16_UP} // Used in code
  {$DEFINE DELPHI17_UP} // Used in zeos.inc only
  {$DEFINE DELPHI18_UP} // Used in zeos.inc only
  {$DEFINE DELPHI19_UP} // Used in zeos.inc only
  {$DEFINE DELPHI20_UP} //By dieletro Used in zeos.inc only
  {$DEFINE DELPHI21_UP} //Used in zeos.inc only
  {$DEFINE BDS4_UP} // Used in code
  {$DEFINE BDS5_UP} // Used in code
{$ENDIF}
```

Сохраняешь, устанавливаешь